# React component: Array structure different to expected

Tags: json, reactjs, api

I've written a presentational component (https://github.com/studioraygun/react-dropdown-list) but now I want to use it in another project I've hit a stumbling block.

I want a show a list of data which comes from an API but the data is formatted very differently to what the component expects. I think I have two options:

1) Write a sub-component which lets me generate the actual list using the map function

2) Find a way to "alias" or rename the array keys being sent by the API

Neither approach feels ideal, and I wondered if there might be a more sensible way?

Comment: You can use a HOC for wrapping this component and every time sending the data to it and reshape the data there.

https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Comment: I think this is just what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Or you could reshape the data inside constructor function! No need to create another component then!

Comment: @Chathuranga94 please can you elaborate on this?

Comment: You could just copy the component to new project. This component would get `this.props.data` which is data in new format. In the constructor do necessary transition to convert `this.props.data` -> `this.state.data`. Here `this.state.data` will be the old format that is applicable to previous component! And make sure rest of the component depends on `this.state.data` afterwards!